# Retrieve data only from Mysql Innodb .ibd file on Mac OS

Tags: mysql, macos, innodb

I am a newbie to Mysql/Mac OS. Yesterday I turned my laptop (Yosemite 10.10.5) on and found that mysql workbench 6.3 was complaining when retrieving data from one of my tables:

> **Error Code: 1932. Table 'mydb.mytable' doesn't exist in engine**

I cant think why this would suddenly start happening. The ibd file is 2.4GB but I guess that makes no difference.

The table is stored in INNODB format.

All I need to do is get the data, even if its in a text file or something, I dont care about relinking the data back into MySQL. At this stage all I care about is the data.

I've tried various things:

- innodb_force_recovery (values from 0-6) (same error occurred)
- PERCONA innodb recovery tool (i couldnt get it to compile)
- deleting and recreating tablespaces (same error occurred)
- http://www.chriscalender.com/tag/innodb-error-tablespace-id-in-file/ - but this does not give me the error he says it should, hence he thinks I should be able to dump my table (which I cant) as the same error occurs.

I'm at my wits end. Is there any way to get my data back? Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: if you have set innodb_file_per_table    = 1 ? when yes, look in the datadir if there a 2 files .ibd and one .frm file with your tablename

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. The two files you mentioned are in my datadir. My .cnf file says this:     
innodb_file_per_table

Comment: do you have virtual columns in your table ? and which Mysql Version you are using "select version();"

Comment: No, I dont have any virtual columns, the version is 10.0.17-MariaDB.

Comment: do you have the create from the table

Comment: try this : ALTER TABLE mytable IMPORT TABLESPACE; save the ibd file before

Comment: sorry, im not sure what you mean? if you mean do i have the table structure then yes i do have that.

Comment: I tried the "ALTER TABLE mytable IMPORT TABLESPACE" thing yesterday. I tried it again right now and i got the same error: Error Code: 1932. Table 'dbdocuments1.documents' doesn't exist in engine

Comment: so you can create a new table with the name mytable_new. Then "ALTER TABLE mytable_new DISCARD TABLESPACE;" , shutdown server, copy the orig ibd file to mytable_new.ibd . start server and " ALTER TABLE mytable_new IMPORT TABLESPACE" . then test the new table

Comment: ok, im sure i tried i something similar yesterday. but i tried it again:  
1. in a new database “test1”, i created a new table “documents1” with the same format as my original table “documents”.  
2. i ran ALTER TABLE documents1 DISCARD TABLESPACE;  
3. i went to the XAMPP manage servers window and stopped the MYSQL database  
4. i copied documents.ibd to documents1.ibd  
5. i went to XAMPP manage servers window and started the MYSQL database  
6. i entered ALTER TABLE documents1 IMPORT TABLESPACE but it gave the same error:  
Error Code: 1932. Table 'test1.documents1' doesn't exist in engine

Comment: (Sorry the formatting on the answer above is rubbish and adding two spaces at the end of the line doesnt seem to work)

Comment: Heres what the error log says:   2015-12-23 11:10:57 14f04a000  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
151223 11:10:57 [ERROR] InnoDB: Trying to import a tablespace, but could not open the tablespace file ./test1/documents1.ibd
151223 11:10:57 [Note] InnoDB: Discarding tablespace of table "test1"."documents1": Tablespace not found

Comment: So, i did a chmod 555 on the ibd file and tried the ALTER TABLE documents1 IMPORT TABLESPACE  again and although i got an error (0 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1810 IO Read error: (2, No such file or directory) Error opening './test1/documents1.cfg', will attempt to import without schema verification
) it did pull all the data in. THANKS a lot for your help @Bernd Buffen.

Comment: Can you see the table from the mysql commandline tool?

Comment: @RickJames Never used that tool to be honest. GIve me a quick rundown of how to and I'll try it. Thanks.

Comment: Get a terminal window.  Type "mysql" (assuming it is in your path).  Type SQL commands.  How did you do the ALTERs discussed without the tool?

Comment: hi. i did the ALTERs from a SQL WorkBench query window. the "mysql" command works in that i get a prompt like this "MariaDB [(none)]>". Then what do I do? Ive tried some SQL but it just says "->". Thanks.

Comment: Did you try https://github.com/twindb/undrop-for-innodb ? But it's only for Linux. Probably that's why Percona's tool didn't compile as well.

Comment: hi, i saw the twindb stuff but didnt try to do anything with it.

Comment: Post https://twindb.com/recover-corrupt-mysql-database/ is closest to your case, but you are going to need a linux machine (try it on a virtualbox or whatever your favorite VM). Or you can upload your ibd file on https://recovery.twindb.com and get a dump back. Ping me privately if you have questions.

Comment: @akuzminsky thanks for your post pal. i have fixed my issue as per my post from Dec 23 11:18. Ill keep the twindb thing in mind, sounds useful. Thanks!